# Irreducibility of directed graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I am new to graph theory but I have some knowledge about Markov Chains.That is for example a state $j$ (vertex) is recurrent (strongly connected)  if the Markov chain started in $j$ eventually revisits $j$.In graph theory they name it persistent.

In the other hand the state (vertex) $j$ is said to be transient if there is positive probability that the Markov chain started in $j$ never returns to $j$.

A Markov chain now is said to be irreducible if all the states all recurrent.
So in the context of graph theory what does reducibility/irreducibility mean for directed graphs?

Can some please help me with that or indicate me a book that describes these two properties for directed graphs ?

Comment: Essentially it means the entire directed graph forms a strongly connected component, i. e., there is a path from each node to another node.

Comment: @adrien_vdb so a directed graph is reducible if it is strongly connected and irreducible (chain with al least one transient communication class)if it is not strongly connected ?

Comment: Not exactly, if you think of the "communication" forming an equivalence relation, then you can partition your nodes into equivalence classes (which you referred to as transient communication classes), and in your graph there will be a strongly connected component associated to each such class. This is why when the chain is irreducible you end up with a single strongly connected component

Comment: @adrien_vdb So you partition the nodes (states) in order to define the reducibility/irreducibility of the graph ? If the graph (chain) is reducible and I want to find the stationary distribution I can calculate it only in the states that are in a recurrent class ?

Comment: Given your Markov chain on states given by the set of vertices $V$, then two states $i, j\in V$ are communicating if in the underlying graph there exists path from node $i$ to node $j$ and a path from node $j$ to node $i$. The Markov chain is deemed irreducible if $\textbf{all}$ states are communicating. By definition, this also means that the underlying graph forms a strongly connected component.

Comment: If on the other hand the chain is not irreducible, then some states are not communicating, but then you can partition the set of states into classes which communicate. In the underlying graph, you will see that it is not a big strongly connected component anymore, but rather multiple strongly connected component (which are connected together), corresponding to those various classes of communicating states.

Comment: @adrien_vdb I understood.Final question:Is there any book that describes all these (connectivity with Markov chains and graph theory) with any programming language  application examples?

Comment: You may be interested in these lecture notes https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee126/fa18/markov-chains.pdf, but it's mostly the theoretical side